# Laravel No query results for model [App\Topic] create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get a view where the user is able to create a topic. I did this many times in my project but never got this error, Because all of the other ones work just fine.

I get the error `No query results for model [App\Topic] create`. Here is the code.

This is the link that is supposed to bring the user to the view.

```
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content clearfix">
                    <a href="{{ route('createtopic', ['theme_id' => $theme->id]) }}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-4">New topic <i class="material-icons right">edit</i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

These are the routes that are used in this problem.

```
Route::get('/theme/{theme_id}/topics/create', 'TopicsController@create')->name('createtopic');
Route::post('/theme/{theme_id}/topics/create', 'TopicsController@store')->name('savetopic');
```

The Controller method create.

```
dd('Hij is er ' . $id);
```

And the store method is empty, The link doesn't show the DumpDie method but shows me the error instead. So there is no need to post the view i'm trying to display because that's not where the problem is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check whether you are passing the correct id in blade file. do dd in the method where you are returning this blade.

Comment: I'm not returning the view because that's where the dd is. The problem is not in the create method but somewhere else. I don't know where, that's the problem

Comment: It means no row exist with this id in your databse

Comment: But I'm not even trying to get a row with the name create, I did not define that anywhere? That's why i dont know. All the code above is all the code related to this. @Vikash look at this: http://imgur.com/a/Slw4i

Comment: Edit the question and show some related code maybe controller code, which is depending, so that i can have clear picture of that

Comment: without hitting this url '/theme/{someid}/topics/create', create method will not being called, if not called how you are getting error, show some code for clear picture

Comment: There is nothing in the controller, Thats the problem. All the code in my question is related to the problem Nothing more. That's all the code.

Comment: which url you are hitting and getting error. can you give me the exact url ?

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('createtopic', ['theme_id' => $theme->id]) }}">`

Comment: No give me the exact url, not route, how are you getting error, i mean after hitting with url in browser ?

Comment: The URL is supposed to be /theme/{theme_id}/topics/create. 
This is what I can get for you. when i click the link with the route, I get the error. When i try to use that link, I get the error

Comment: check my answer, how it should work, ping me if anything is unclear. you have to pass the argument in your url instead of theme_id, otherwise whenever you will fetch from modal it will search for a row in your table with id theme_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how routes and controller methods are working

```
Route::get('/theme/{theme_id}/topics/create', 'TopicsController@create')->name('createtopic');
```

When you are hitting the above route, i mean something for example `yourdomain/theme/1/topics/create` in your browser, then it will take `1` in place of `theme_id` and it will go to the `create` method of your `TopicsController` which will accept one argument.

Your create method should be something like that

```
public function create($id)
{
   dd($id);
}
```

Here you will get 1 as result, because you have passed this argument in your url instead of theme_id.

Comment: You don't get the problem. I have the exact same thing as u just posted here but it doesn't even get into the create method. It just shows me the error code. There is nothing wrong with the code I used because I used it many times in my project and there it works fine. The URL works fine also that's not the problem. I don't know where the problem is

Comment: Are you using route modal binding ?

Comment: Also try to clear cache by all four artisan command and, delete the compile class by running `php artisan clear-compiled`.